# How to sort csv data by changing data value in rows to columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

There are a total of 25 `LOC_CODE`, which means locations.
There are a total of 6 `ITEM_CODE`, which corresponds to CO2 level, CO level...etc.

The item_codes are: 1,3,5,6,8, and 9

The problem:
I want to sort this dataset and overwrite the same csv such that there are only 25 rows where each row is a unique location `LOC_CODE`.
And I want to display values of all six item_codes per location so it's not one `item_code` per row like in the screenshot. Everything else stays the same. I just want to display values of all six `ITEM_CODE` for a unique location on a single row.

Comment: is it necessary to use pandas here? will a solution without using pandas suffice u?

Comment: yea pandas is not necessary... anything to resolve the problem would help!

Comment: also, kindly include a screenshot (make one yourself) of the expected output as well.. so that it makes it clear for us.. i.e., tell us what columns from the above are required to be kept in your expected output

Comment: in your second scrnsht its not clear whether the date time stuff should be taken from `DATA_DT` or `REGIST_DT` kindly make it clear (better if u include in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that the response from the API is already saved into a CSV file in the format given in the first screenshot. I'm using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` from the `csv` module.

Before beginning, let's just import `csv` using:

```py
import csv
```

---

Let's first create a function that'll process the `DATA_DT` into a desirable format

```py
def get_datetime(value: str):
    # returns year, month, day, time (hh:mm:ss), in that order
    # assumes string length is 14 and has format 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss'
    y, m, d = value[0:4], value[4:6], value[6:8]
    t = ':'.join([value[8:10], value[10:12], value[12:14]])
    return y, m, d, t
```

a dictionary for `ITEM_CODE`:

```py
item_dict = {'1': 'SO2', '3': ...}  # please fill this yourself
```

and the headers list needed for the CSV DictWriter:

```py
headers = ['Location', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Time (24h)', 'Station No.',
           'SO2', 'NO2', 'CO', 'O3', 'PM10', 'PM2.5', 'Meter Status']
```

---

We open the CSV file and read from it into a list `raw_data` (fill the filename, please). Each element of `raw_data` is a dict:

```py
with open(r'filepath\filename.csv') as file:
    raw_data = list(csv.DictReader(file))
```

We now create an empty dict `data`, and then iterate over `raw_data`, processing its data and writing it to the dict (comments added at necessary places):

```py
data = {}

for rec in raw_data:
    loc = rec['LOC_CODE']
    if loc not in data:
        data[loc] = dict.fromkeys(headers, '')
    
    # rec is from old data, record is for the new data
    record = data[loc]
    
    if not record['Year']:
        # assumed that date & time for a location is same for all ITEM_CODE
        (record['Year'],
        record['Month'],
        record['Day'],
        record['Time (24h)']
        ) = get_datetime(rec['DATA_DT'])
    
    record['Station No.'] = rec['DATA_STATE']
    record['Meter Status'] = rec['DATA_NOVER']
    # for the readings we get the apt key using item_dict
    record[item_dict[rec['ITEM_CODE']]] = rec['DATA_VALUE']
```

Finally, we arrange all the records in `data` into a list of `dict`s the way `csv.DictWriter` would expect and write it into the output CSV file (please fill in the filename yourself):

```py
records = [{**v, 'Location': k} for k, v in data.items()]

with open(r'filepath\newfilename.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(records)
```

(All the `ITEM_CODE`s that do not have a value in your table will display an empty cell in the created CSV)

---

You must, of course, tune this code to your requirements - if you want it to not delete existing data from the CSV **please** change the mode from `'w'` to `'a'` or `'r+'` and modify the data writing part of the code accordingly. And similarly, if you wanna sort the data by date, or whatever, descending, do the same before beginning.

Should I combine all the code into one or leave it to the reader, comment below... ;P